# translation error in translating c# to vb .net using newton.jsoft (json.net) in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, json, vb.net, linq, json.net

What is wrong with this code:
error in translating c# to vb .net using newton.jsoft (json.net) in visual studio 2012:
Original code:

```
 public static List<TradeInfo> GetTrades(BtcePair pair)
    {
        string queryStr = string.Format("https://btc-e.com/api/2/{0}/trades", BtcePairHelper.ToString(pair));
        return JArray.Parse(WebApi.Query(queryStr)).OfType<JObject>().Select(TradeInfo.ReadFromJObject).ToList();
    }
```

Translated code:

```
Public Shared Function GetTrades(pair As BtcePair) As List(Of TradeInfo)
    Dim queryStr As String = String.Format("https://btc-e.com/api/2/{0}/trades", _
                                                BtcePairHelper.ToString(pair))
    Return JArray.Parse(WebApi.Query(queryStr)).OfType(Of JObject)().[Select](TradeInfo.ReadFromJObject).ToList()
End Function
```

Error:

> Error 1 Argument not specified for parameter 'o' of 'Public Shared Function ReadFromJObject(o As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject) As TradeInfo'.

Called function (vb):

```
Public Shared Function ReadFromJObject(o As JObject) As TradeInfo
    If o Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

 Return New TradeInfo() With 
  {.Amount = o.Value(Of Decimal)("amount"), _
    .Price = o.Value(Of Decimal)("price"), _
    .[Date] = UnixTime.ConvertToDateTime(o.Value(Of Long)("date")), _
    .Item = BtceCurrencyHelper.FromString(o.Value(Of String)("item")), _
    .PriceCurrency = BtceCurrencyHelper.FromString(o.Value(Of String)
    ("price_currency")), _
    .Tid = o.Value(Of Long)("tid"), _
    .Type = TradeInfoTypeHelper.FromString(o.Value(Of String)("trade_type")) _
    }
End Function
```

Comment: IIRC, you need `AddressOf`.

Comment: Your C# and VB versions are not similar at all - in what way did you convert one to the other?

Comment: with online tool at http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: Slaks was right, it builds well. Will test soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need an "AddressOf" since you're not actually invoking 'ReadFromJObject':

```
Public Shared Function GetTrades(ByVal pairlist() As BtcePair, Optional ByVal limit As Integer = 150) As Dictionary(Of BtcePair, List(Of TradeInfoV3))
    Dim tradeInfoListReader As Func(Of JContainer, List(Of TradeInfoV3)) = (Function(x) x.OfType(Of JObject)().Select(AddressOf TradeInfoV3.ReadFromJObject).ToList())
    Return MakeRequest(Of List(Of TradeInfoV3))("trades", pairlist, tradeInfoListReader, New Dictionary(Of String, String)() From {{ "limit", limit.ToString() }}, True)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the C# code returns a Dictionary while the VB code returns a List.  Secondly, the two methods have different numbers and types of parameters.  I haven't looked beyond that.